# DNS not working on 16.04

Tags: networking, 16.04, network-manager, dns

I'm using an **HP MicroServer Gen8** which has two network ports - but have the same issue with both.

I've tried resetting all network-related settings. I then connected using the remaining `ifupdown` connection and was able to ping IP addresses but not domain names. So I assume it's a DNS issue. I can SSH into it.

I have a Pi-Hole (an ad-blocking local DNS server) on the network, so tried bypassing this by adding a new Ethernet connection which uses Google's 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 servers, but this made no difference.

Unsure what to try next as there seem to be various ways to configure network settings and it's not clear what works on 16.04.

Background: I've had a few issues with the server recently and was unable to boot for a while. I used a boot repair disk to get back into it, but have had this issue since.

I'm also happy to upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu if that might fix it, though I'd need a way of doing that without functioning DNS…

Comment: I do not know if an upgrade will fix it BUT 16.04 goes EOL in April of this year so an upgrade should be made soon.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question in case it should help anyone else in the future:

I upgraded to 18.04, by editing my hosts file to assign IP addresses to the required domains. Listed here for reference, ping them to get the IPs.

gb.archive.ubuntu.com
security.ubuntu.com
ppa.launchpad.net
apt.postgresql.org
changelogs.ubuntu.com
archive.ubuntu.com
deb.nodesource.com
api.snapcraft.io

The update worked but then I had no network connection at all. But I could now fix this by changing managed=false to managed=true in /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf and then adding a new network connection.